# How to retrieve information in Django - Post Request?

Tags: javascript, django, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to send a JavaScript array to Django via ajax, as follows:

```
document.getElementById('input-generate').onclick = () => {

    // Get the token
    const csrftoken = document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value;

    // Create new request add token 
    const generateRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    generateRequest.open('POST', '/generate');
    generateRequest.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrftoken);

    generateRequest.onload = () => {

        console.log('generateRequest');

    };

    // Add the motif to send with the request
    const data = new FormData();
    console.log(notes);
    // [{…}] 0: {duration: "4", note: "E4", dot: false} length: 1 __proto__: Array(0)
    data.append('motif', notes);

    // Send request
    generateRequest.send(data);
};
```

On views.py:

```
@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def generate(request):

    # See if method was post
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Retrive seed
        seed = request.POST.get("motif")
        print(seed)
        print(type(seed))

        # Sanity check
        if not seed:
            return JsonResponse({"succes": False}, status=400)

        # Return the seed
        return JsonResponse({"seed": seed}, status=200)
```

But when I print seed and type(seed) I only see:

```
[object Object]
<class 'str'>
```

How can I print the actual array I am sending?

BTW: I am trying to send and array of strings that encode notes, as an example:

notes = [{duration: "4", note: "E4", dot: false}, {duration: "8", note: "D4", dot: false}, {duration: "2", note: "F4", dot: false}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to call `JSON.stringify` on your `notes` array for it to send correctly. Especially because your content-type will be form-data. Then Django should parse the incoming JSON in your view.

Example changes to your JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('input-generate').onclick = () => {

    let notes = [{duration: "4", note: "E4", dot: false}]  // sample data

    // Get the token
    const csrftoken = document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value;

    // Create new request add token 
    const generateRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    generateRequest.open('POST', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/watchdesk');
    generateRequest.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrftoken);

    // Add the motif to send with the request
    const data = new FormData();
    console.log(notes);
    data.append('motif', JSON.stringify(notes));  // stringify notes

    // Send request
    generateRequest.send(data);
};
```

I just tested this without making any changes to the view and it seems to work.

Comment: Oh thank you very much!! Now is working as expected =)

Comment: No problem. In addition to accepting, you can also upvote answers too if they help. :-) Happy coding!

Comment: Done! But it says that I need more than 15 reputation to be publicly displayed